# PowerShell dot source within a dot sourced file - import classes

Tags: powershell, class, powershell-module

My project is structured like this:

```
MyScript.ps1
classes\
    Car.ps1
    Tesla.ps1
```

Car.ps1 is the base class of Tesla.ps1. I attempt to define Tesla like this in Tesla.ps1:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\Car.ps1"

class Tesla : Car
{
}
```

MyScript.ps1 needs to use the Tesla class, but shouldn't need to know that it inherits from Car.

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\classes\Tesla.ps1"

$tesla = [Tesla]::new()
```

Dot sourcing to `classes\Tesla.ps1` works fine, but this error is thrown from the Tesla file:

> Unable to find type [Car]

If I import all the files in the correct order in MyScript.ps1, it works fine. Example:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\classes\Car.ps1"
. "$PSScriptRoot\classes\Tesla.ps1"

$tesla = [Tesla]::new()
```

This is cumbersome, especially as the complexity grows. Am I dot sourcing incorrectly? Is there a better way to import a custom PowerShell class using a relative path that isn't in the PSModulePath?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as countless times before, has provided the crucial pointers in a terse comment on the question:

**Due to your use of *classes*, you must use *modules* and import them with [`using module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using) statements** in order to use them.

Specifically, **in order to reference a type (class) in a `class` definition, that type must be known to PowerShell *at parse time***.

In your example, in order to derive `Tesla` from class `Car`, type `Car` must be known to PowerShell when the script is *parsed*, *before* execution begins - that's why **it is *too late* to try to import `Car` by dot-sourcing its containing script** (`. "$PSScriptRoot\Car.ps1"`)

PowerShell knows about referenced types at parse time in one of two ways:

- If the type is *already loaded* into the current PowerShell session
- Via a `using module` statement that references a module in which the type (class) is defined (note that there's also a `using assembly` statement for loading types from DLLs, and `using namespace` to enable referring to types by their mere names).

  - Note that the related `Import-Module` cmdlet does *not* work in this case, because it executes at *runtime*.

Therefore, as PetSerAl suggests:

- **Store your classes in *module* files** (stand-alone `*.psm1` files in the simplest case)
- Then **use `using module`** to have the `Tesla` module import the `Car` module and the `MyScript.ps1` script import the `Tesla` module, using **paths that are relative to the enclosing script / module's location**.

```bash
MyScript.ps1
classes\
    Car.psm1    # Note the .psm1 extension
    Tesla.psm1  # Ditto
```

`Car.psm1`:

```bash
class Car {}
```

`Tesla.psm1`:

```bash
using module .\Car.psm1

class Tesla : Car {}
```

`MyScript.ps1`:

```bash
using module .\classes\Tesla.psm1

$tesla = [Tesla]::new()
```

Comment: Thanks, @benvdh - it wasn't documented at the time I wrote the answer. I've updated the answer to include your link.